# How get results where column type=image,null not empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have column name `image`, type - `image, null`

I want get results where `image` not NULL.

I use query:

```
SELECT * FROM Farm f WHERE f.name=2 AND f.colum=12 AND f.image != NULL
```

but i get error:

```
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, 
except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.
```

Anyone know how aright get result where image not NULL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Farm f WHERE f.name=2 AND f.colum=12 AND f.image IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: nice, thank you) i cannt accept now, need 12 minutes when i can accept answer.